# Evolving questions and voting

Tags: discussion, questions, tags

Today, I replied to a post.  It was the first reply.  The post wasn't very clear and I made a guess as to what the OP wanted.  It appeared that he didn't understand array indexes.  However, as the question "evolved" or was edited to become clearer, my answer slowly became irrelevant and to someone just browsing it may appear irrelevant.  I'm guessing that's why someone downvoted it.  Now, I don't care too much about voting or scoring, but I do care about answers becoming obsolete.

If questions can be modified and there is no active "conversation" of that modification it can be misleading.

How does Stack Overflow prevent "evolving post syndrome."  Maybe allow the answers to be tagged as no longer relevant?

[Is there a cleaner syntax for applying an operation to each element of a sequence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396521/is-there-a-cleaner-syntax-for-applying-an-operation-to-each-element-of-a-sequen#396534)

Answer (score 8):

If your answer is now irrelevant and or wrong, then you are encouraged to delete it; or make the appropriate edits (but only if you are adding additional value, if someone else has answered correctly, just delete your bad one).

Its much better for a question to have a few correct answers, rather than a few correct answers *and* lots of downvoted incorrect answers, that just adds clutter for no good reason.

Answer (score 1):

Guess one existing mechanism is for those with 2000+ reputation point to make updates to the question itself.

However, I do agree. On StackOverflow, there is a problem that the "Question - Answer" format (intentionally) does not contain discussions well, whereas comments are often not read.

One solution might be more aggressive deletions of the weaker answer to declutter things. The other is more aggressive edits to the answers. Both can be done within the current framework and only require behavioral changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can see all edited versions of the question. 
When the question change some answers will not fit and will travel down the list. But I think the best way is to up-voting the more correct answers rather than down-voting.

Better to vote the correct one up than the not so correct down is my philosophy.

Answer (score 0):

This is a weakness of the system.  It might be nice to have a feature which notifies you when questions you have answered are edited, but that could get spammy with minor edits, so then again it may not be so useful.

My tendency is to ask for clarification in a comment if I feel a question is poorly worded, even if I think I know what is being asked for.  Otherwise, be prepared to revisit your answer and delete or edit it, as others have suggested.

The intent of the site is that people will monitor their own answers and modify/delete them as appropriate.  It's unlikely that high-rep users will delete your answer, as that requires a lot of effort making inferences as to the state of the question at the time when you answered it, and guessing about your preferences as to whether it should be deleted.  From what I've seen, it's left up to you to delete answers.